# Navigator pop when using persistent_bottom_nav_bar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am currently using `persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^4.0.2` and `rflutter_alert` but the problem is when I call  `Navigator.of(context).pop();` I always get this error:

```
FlutterError (This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.)
```

That happens when I use `persistent_bottom_nav_bar`, I have tried to use `bottomNavigationBar` which is a property of `Scaffold` widget, and that's really fine and there is no problem with  `Navigator.of(context).pop();`. Is there a way to do Navigator pop when using `persistent_bottom_nav_bar`

Comment: can you show the showDialog code

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
 Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.error,
      title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
      desc: "Flutter is more awesome with RFlutter Alert.",
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "COOL",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop(),
          width: 120,
        )
      ],
    ).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution after reading this discussion: https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert/issues/20#issuecomment-535330620. So, instead of using `Navigator.of(context).pop();` I change it to `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
    Navigator.pop(context);
```